# webpack-dev-server error on node js app deployment on gcloud

Tags: node.js, webpack-dev-server, gcloud

I am trying to deploy my node js application on gcloud app engine. Project uses `web pack-dev-server` as a dev dependency. When I run it on gcloud as a localhost using `npm install` all works fine and there is no compilation error. But when I am deploying using `gcloud app deploy` I get the error below.

`> webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot --progres`

`ssh: 1:webpack-dev-server: not found`

I tried giving root access to node_module folder. I am using node v6.11.0 and npm 3.6.0. Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Does `gcloud app deploy` actually install dev dependencies? If not, I'd guess that will be the issue (however, using `webpack-dev-server` in production isn't really something you'd want to do anyway).

Comment: @robertklep Yes gcloud app deploy does install dev dependencies. I agree I should not be using web pack-dev-server for production but my main concern here is how to make the app run on gcloud. No resolution to it

Comment: @robertklep I am having the same issue as the OP. I am using webpack3 and webpack-dev-server2. I did this web-app following [MDC-Get started guide](https://material.io/components/web/docs/getting-started/), but deployment is not covered. What should I do if I want to deploy correctly? Simply uninstall webpack-dev-server? Or replace it with another dependency? Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: @chimos I'm not familiar with gcloud so I can only guess, but I think that gcloud will try to run `npm start` when you deploy, which in your case will start `webpack-dev-server` (because of the `scripts.start` entry in `package.json`). Try removing that entry and check if gcloud works better (you can always start `webpack-dev-server` manually in your dev environment, you don't really need a "start" script for that, it's merely a convenient shortcut).